# Do miners check whether a transaction is segwit or non-segwit?

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, validation

When a transaction is pushed directly to a miner does it check whether the transaction is segwit or not, or only if it is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The miner only determines if it is valid. Miners do not, in a sense, "discriminate" between Segwit or Legacy.

Comment: I think legacy miner(pre-segwit) needs to distinguish between anyone-can-spend transactions and legacy transactions for the simple reason that they can't validate segwit transactions.

Comment: @sanket1729 No, by definition they can't, as they don't even know about the existance of segwit. All they see is a weird but valid output that anyone can spend. They're not aware of the new rules that do not make them so trivial.

Comment: @PieterWuille, should there not be any policy in the legacy miners to not include transactions which contain anyone can spend outputs since they cannot risk creating an invalid block?

Comment: @sanket1729 Sure, there is; in the case of BIP141, that policy rule is the CLEANSTACK rule (which requires the final state of the stack after scriptPubKey execution to contain a single non-zero element): BIP141 scriptPubKeys push **two** elements for exactly that reason. But I still wouldn't quite call that discriminating between segwit and non-segwit, only discriminating based on an old policy rule, which segwit helpfully is designed to trigger.